# TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() throws an error on .Net 4 but not .Net4.5

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

So I have the line:

```
updaterScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
```

Which has worked fine on my debug machine (Windows 8.1) and on my virtual Windows 7 machines with `.Net 4.5` installed.

But when I test it on my Windows 7 machine with `.Net 4 Client Profile` and `.Net 4 Extended` this line throws the error:

> The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler

My project is Targeting `.Net 4` so I'm unsure as to why this is happening? Is there a work around for this issue?

Comment: Is `SynchronizationContext.Current` null?

Comment: @Lee Yes, on `.net4` `SynchronizationContext.Current` is null and on `.Net4.5` it is not. What is the work around for this?